# Else without a previous If problem in C language in URI Online Judge

Tags: c, if-statement, compiler-errors, conditional-statements, uri

I was solving URI 1099 problem and got stuck into an error. It said:

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:22:17: error: ‘else’ without a previous ‘if’
                 else{
                 ^~~~
main.c:36:17: error: ‘else’ without a previous ‘if’
                 else{
                 ^~~~
```

The code was not compiled. The compiler sent above errors. I could not fix that.
The full code is written below:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int N, X, Y, i, j, k, sum1=0, sum2=0;
    scanf("%d", &N);

    for(i=0; i<=N; i++){
    scanf("%d %d\n",&X,&Y);

        if(X<Y){
            for(j=X+1; j<Y; j++){
                if(j%2!=0){
                    sum1=sum1+j;
                }
                printf("%d", sum1);
                else{
                    printf("%d", 0);
                }
            }
        }
        
        else if(X>Y){
            for(k=Y+1; k<X; k++){
                if(k%2!=0){
                    sum2=sum2+k;
                }
                printf("%d", sum2);
                else{
                    printf("%d", 0);
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            printf("%d", 0);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It will be very helpful for me if anyone notices the problem.

Comment: You have printf command before else

Comment: If you used consistent indentation your error would have been obvious.  There are many reasons why experienced developers ***ALWAYS*** use consistent code formatting.

Answer (score 2):

You can not write anything between if and else condition.

```
 if(k%2!=0){
                sum2=sum2+k;
                }
                printf("%d", sum2);  //this will faill.
                
                else{
                printf("%d", 0);
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an `if` statement followed by a `printf` followed by an `else` in multiple code sections, that is not allowed. You either have to place the `printf` after the block or in the block.

This is one of the code section to be corrected, others are very similar

```c
if(j%2!=0){
    sum1=sum1+j;
}
// This printf causes the error
printf("%d", sum1);
            
else {
    printf("%d", 0);
}
```

and this can be a solution

```c
if(j%2!=0) {
    sum1=sum1+j;
    printf("%d", sum1);
} else {
    printf("%d", 0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you guys. I get the solution and fix the problem successfully.

Comment: Remember to vote an answer

Answer (score 1):

You can't write any other command before else because that would end if else block.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
    int N, X, Y, i, j, k, sum1=0, sum2=0;
    scanf("%d", &N);
    
    for(i=0; i<=N; i++){
    scanf("%d %d\n",&X,&Y);
    
        if(X<Y){
            for(j=X+1; j<Y; j++){
                
                if(j%2!=0){
                sum1=sum1+j;
                }
                printf("%d", sum1); //this can't be here
            
                else{
                printf("%d", 0);
                }
            }
        }
        
        else if(X>Y){
            for(k=Y+1; k<X; k++){
                
                if(k%2!=0){
                sum2=sum2+k;
                }
                printf("%d", sum2); //this can't be here
                
                else{
                printf("%d", 0);
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            printf("%d", 0);
        }
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

Correct would be:

```
     if(k%2!=0){
         sum2=sum2+k;
         printf("%d", sum2);
     }
```

or:

```
 if(k%2!=0) { ... }
 else {...}
 printf(...)
```

depending on what you need but i assume it is the first one.